# Hide or Unhide based on tablix in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I am supposed to show textbox based on Tablix. It will be appear on the page where the tablix exists. It stops showing when the report page doesn't exist on the page. How can I achieve it? 
I am thinking of using reportItems but I don't know exactly how. 
I have already one column in my tablix for using reportitem. Can I have two report items in the same tablix( that one I am not sure too)? 
Am I clear in explaining my issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking if the Tablix exists on a page, perhaps think about what data causes the Tablix to exist.

Say your Tablix is displaying data on dogs, but on one of your pages you don't have any valid dogs, so no Tablix. In this case you could check for this in the `Hidden` property of the Text Box:

```
=IIF(Count(Fields!DOG_ID.Value) = 0, True, False)
```

(For the opposite of this, a Tablix has a `NoRowsMessage` property you can set rather than needing an extra Text Box.)

Comment: The text box is happened to be in Header. Shall it be working for =iif(reportitems!DOG_ID.Value=0,True,False) too ?

Comment: You're right to refer to a ReportItem rather than a data field for an expression in the header. That should work, unless you find the DOG_ID text box is empty rather than zero. In that case, you'd use `=IIF(IsNothing(ReportItems!DOG_ID.Value), False, True)` instead.

Comment: Thanks for verifying it.

Answer (score 0):

Goto the properties of the text box and then goto Visibility. Select "Show or hide based on expression" and click on the [fx] button.

**To show or hide depending if the Tablix returns any data or not:**

Then enter the below: =iif(CountRows("NameOfTheDataseOfTheTablix") < 1,True, False)